# Como obter a média entre 2 colunas MYSQL

Tags: mysql, query, select, count, sum

Estou precisando muito de uma ajuda estou fazendo uma consulta em um banco de dados em MySQL.

Nome da tabela = `tb_diario`:

Estou tentando o seguinte

```
SELECT Disciplina, 
 COUNT(*) AS Qtd_de_alunos 
  FROM tb_diario 
 GROUP BY Disciplina;
```

Mas não sei como calcular a média  entre os campos `Nota1` e `Nota2`,  e também não sei  separar os totais de alunos aprovados e reprovados

Obs: maior e igual a 6 -> aprovado   / Menor que 6 -> Reprovado

isso é possível ?

| Disciplina | Matricula_do_aluno | Nota1 | Nota2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Eng1111 | 10222 | 10 | 6 |
| Eng1111 | 12333 | 4 | 4 |
| Inf5333 | 13444 | 10 | 10 |
| Inf5333 | 14555 | 8 | 8 |

Gostaria de Obter o seguinte resultado abaixo;

| Disciplinas | Qtd_de_alunos | Qtd_Aprov | Qtd_Reprov |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Eng1111 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Inf5333 | 2 | 2 | 0 |

Comment: *"Mas não sei como calcular a média entre os campos Nota1 e Nota2"* já tentou `((Nota1+nota2)/2)`? *"não sei separar os totais de alunos aprovados e reprovados"* ai fica difícil ajudar se tem a estrutura da tabela, o campo que define isso.. melhore a pergunta e ponha mais detalhes

Comment: Obrigado amigo valeu mesmo

Answer (score 0):

```
/*classifica*/
SELECT Disciplina,
       (case when ((nota1+nota2)/2) >= 6 then 'Aprv' Else 'Reprv' end) situacao
FROM tb_diario GROUP BY Disciplina;


/*conta*/
select disciplina,
       situacao,
       count(*) qtd
from
(
SELECT Disciplina,
       (case when ((nota1+nota2)/2) >= 6 then 'Aprv' Else 'Reprv' end) situacao
FROM tb_diario GROUP BY Disciplina
) tab_virtual
group by disciplina,
         situacao;
         
         
/*usa uma tabela virtual , nao tenho certeza da sintaxe do CASE
nao fiz o pivot
sem teste */
```

Comment: Show de bola obrigado